# On Dynkin diagramms and Graph Theory

Tags: graph-theory

I would like to know whether there are some obvious relation between Dynkin Diagramms and Graph Theory in its more general formulation, and, if so, I am particularly interested in knowing:

1) whether Dynkin diagramms constitute some well-defined subset of graphs;
2) whether there are some theorems allowing to "translate" results from one domain into another.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Using this resource for [Dynkin Diagramm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynkin_diagram), I can tell you that these are not graphs, strictly speaking.  They mention that there are possibly double or triple lines, and that the lines may be directed.  In the case where there are multiple edges between the same two vertices (parallel edges in graph theoretic terminology), and when we also have directed edges, this is known as a multi-digraph.  That being said, any theorem that is true for multi-digraphs should also apply to Dynkin Diagramms.  Not sure if there are any useful applications here, but probably worth exploring.